# Why does JSON flattening with a colon work?

Tags: json

When I installed Azurite it re-wrote my secrest.json in the following format:

```
{
  "All": "secrets.json",
  "ConnectionStrings:AzureStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "ConnectionStrings:AzureStorage:blob": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "ConnectionStrings:LouisHoweDb": "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=LouisHowe",
  "ConnectionStrings:UserDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ASDC_Users",
  "secrets": "1",
  "SendGridKey": "abc",
  "Twilio:AccountSID": "def",
  "Twilio:AuthToken": "ghi",
  "Twilio:VerifyApiKey": "jkl",
  "ConnectionStrings:AzureStorage:queue": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
}
```

This appears to work. But it uses a : instead of a . - is that valid?

Second, how do I turn the following back into a non-flattened JSON:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings:AzureStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "ConnectionStrings:AzureStorage:blob": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "ConnectionStrings:AzureStorage:queue": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
}
```

is it"

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureStorage.blob": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureStorage.queue": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  },
```

I'm asking because I don't see if/where it is using blob or queue so I have no way to test.

Comment: What's the max depth you could have in the non-flattened object?

Comment: @NickSlash At present it would be ConnectionStrings:AzureStorage:blob and outside of that case it's Twilio.AccountSID. And I know not a bigge which way it is, but I find the unflattened more readable.